# Unable to run Ghost using forever

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ghost-blog

I followed the official Ghost docs ([here](http://support.ghost.org/deploying-ghost)) for how to install and run `forever` on my AWS free-tier Ubuntu box as follows:

Installed forever with `sudo npm install forever -g` as the `ubuntu` user.
Start with `NODE_ENV=production forever start index.js` and get:

```
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: index.js
```

I cannot reach my blog, if I execute `forever list` I get:

```
info:    Forever processes running
data:        uid  command         script   forever pid  id logfile                        uptime  
data:    [0] _hf3 /usr/bin/nodejs index.js 5034    5036    /home/ubuntu/.forever/_hf3.log STOPPED
```

I have also tried the same process as the `ghost` user:

```
$ NODE_ENV=production forever start index.js
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: index.js

$ forever list
info:    Forever processes running
data:        uid  command         script   forever pid  id logfile                       uptime      
data:    [0] wOoE /usr/bin/nodejs index.js 5087    9973    /home/ghost/.forever/wOoE.log 0:0:0:1.684 
data:    [1] cL9U /usr/bin/nodejs index.js 8515    9967    /home/ghost/.forever/cL9U.log 0:0:0:2.966 
data:    [2] igDw /usr/bin/nodejs index.js 9481    9965    /home/ghost/.forever/igDw.log 0:0:0:3.236
```

Comment: Does /home/ubuntu/.forever/_hf3.log have any info?

Comment: ^[[31mERROR: Unable to access Ghost's content path:^[[0m
  EACCES, permission denied '/var/www/ghost/content/apps/298fa7fa6dd6c8ae'

^[[32mCheck that the content path exists and file system permissions are correc$
Help and documentation can be found at http://support.ghost.org.^[[0m
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 0

Comment: Is there any chance that you run "not correct" index.js?.. like maybe you run it in wrong directory - not ghost one?..

Comment: does the folder /var/www/ghost/content/apps/298fa7fa6dd6c8ae exist. (also check permissions for current user not via sudo)

Comment: /var/www/ghost/content/apps/298fa7fa6dd6c8ae does not exist. Permissions are: ghost@ip-172-31-31-195:/var/www/ghost/content/apps$ ls -l /var/www/ghost/content/apps
total 4 -rw-r--r-- 1 ghost ghost 59 May 21 17:30 README.md @SachinNayak

Comment: and does ghost (update: your user id) have access permissions on the apps folder ? Does it have write permissions to the folder "/var/www/ghost/content/apps"

Comment: I thought my previous message shows that ghost is the owner of that dir & will then have write permissions? 

If not - what's the best way to do that for the ghost user? (I'm not 100% sure and don't want to screw it up) @SachinNayak

Comment: the permissions error was in log file /home/ubuntu/.forever/_hf3.log ... that seems to be ubuntu id not ghost id. Quick check - execute the command using ghost user id, and check the log file to see the error you get for ghost user id . i think it would be different. Also - ubuntu does not have permissions on the apps folder